# Unix Path Resolution in C

Tags: c, unix, path

I'm currently in an operating systems class. One of our projects involves creating a simple shell. This involves parsing the line and resolving the path. So I need to account for things like ~ . .. / etc.. Right now I'm trying to come up with a code for easily resolving ".." -- the parent directory.

This is my code so far. My goal is to locate an occurrence of .., then save the second half of the string if there is one, and then strip the .. as well as up to the second '/' before it. So for instance we have:
/1/2/3/../../4/5/6
My goal is, on the first location of .. to save /../4/5/6
and then save 1/2 and concatenate.
Then it should find the next .. and save /4/5/6 to the second half
and the first half should save /1

```
void expandParentDirectory (){

char firstHalf[ 255 ];
char secondHalf[ 255 ];

for( int i = 1; i < tokenSize; i++ ){

    // checking token list for appearance of ".."
    ////// tests
    size_t len = strlen(parsedArguments[i]);
    printf("string length is: %lu \n", len);

    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(parsedArguments[i]); ++j){
        if(parsedArguments[ i ][ j ] == '.' )
            if(parsedArguments[ i ][ j + 1 ] == '.' ){

                if(parsedArguments[ i ][ j + 2 ] != '\0' ){
                    strcpy(secondHalf, &parsedArguments[ i ] [ j + 2 ]);
                }
                // code to expand PWD and move up a directory
                // if (j == 0) {}

                for (int k = j - 2 ; k > 0 ; k--) {
                    if( parsedArguments[ i ][ k ] == '/' ){
                        strncpy( firstHalf, parsedArguments[ i ], k );
                        //firstHalf[ k ] = '\0';

                        free ( parsedArguments[ i ]);
                        parsedArguments[ i ] = strdup( strcat( firstHalf, secondHalf
                    }
                }
                 ));


            }
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions on getting this working correctly? 
Any suggestions on a better approach? 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should post compilable code; what you've posted clearly can't compile because of the `));` after the innermost `for` loop.  Your `strdup(strcat(` line seems to be missing those characters.  You'd probably do best looking for `/../` in the string (`strstr()`); that's simpler and unambiguously what you're looking for.  At the moment, you'd mistreat `/abc/def../ghi` which is a perfectly legitimate path that does not need munging.  You also need to abstract this into a function that is passed `parsedArguments[i]`.

Comment: Note that the string never grows; you should not need to use `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the beauty of realpath() (or I guess because of it) I was not able to use it in my code. I had to do my own work. This is what I came up with. It works fairly well, but is by no means perfect. I am not sure if it is this code or the code that calls it, but I get a lot of bugs when setting the directory repeatedly or call something with .. in it. Besides these issues, I like it well enough.

```
char * pathResolution ( char * path ){

char * specialDirectory[ 3 ] = { ".", "..", "~" };
char * currentPath = getenv( "PWD" );
char * pathTokens[ 50 ];

int pathTokenCount = 0;
int action = -1;

// if it is just "/", no checks needed
if( !strcmp( "/", path) ){
    return path;
}

// get each path token between '/'
for ( path = strtok( path, "/" ); path;
     path = strtok( NULL, "/" )) {
    pathTokens[ pathTokenCount++ ] = path;
}

// check for special characters
for( size_t i = 0; i != pathTokenCount; ++i ) {

    // checks for special characters; sets action
    if( !strcmp( specialDirectory[ 0 ], pathTokens[ i ]) ){ action = 1; }
    else if( !strcmp( specialDirectory[ 1 ], pathTokens[ i ]) ){ action = 1; }
    else if( !strcmp( specialDirectory[ 2 ], pathTokens[ i ]) ){ action = 2; }
    else { action = 3; }

    // action depending on character
    switch( action ){

        case 1:{ // ".."

            int index;
            char * lastSlash = strrchr( currentPath, '/' );
            index = ( int )( lastSlash - currentPath );
            currentPath[ index ] = '\0';

            if( strlen( currentPath ) < 1 ){
                currentPath = "/";
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2: { // "~"

            // ~ can only be first, return null otherwise
            if( i == 0 ){
                currentPath = getenv( "HOME" );
                break;
            }
            else
                return NULL;
        }

        case 3: {

            // appends /text to end of PWD: PWD/...text...
            char buffer[ 255 ];
            if( !strcmp( "/", currentPath) )
                sprintf( buffer, "/%s", pathTokens[ i ] );
            else
                sprintf( buffer, "%s/%s", currentPath, pathTokens[ i ] );

            currentPath = buffer;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;

    }
}

return currentPath;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library function `realpath` will do this for you: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Comment: Yes, `realpath` will do the job, after a fashion, but that fairly clearly isn't the exercise.  The `realpath` function also resolves symbolic links, which this code does not; it is doing a purely textual 'path resolution'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - This is from the man page on Solaris 11 for realpath:      The realpath() function derives, from the  pathname  pointed
     to  by  file_name,  an absolute pathname that names the same
     file, whose resolution does not involve ".", "..",  or  sym-
     bolic  links.  The  generated  pathname is stored as a null-
     terminated string, up  to  a  maximum  of  {PATH_MAX}  bytes
     (defined  in  limits.h(3HEAD)),  in the buffer pointed to by
     resolved_name.  -- Please note it does NOT resolve symbolic links

Comment: @jimmcnamara: au contraire: it clearly states that the resulting path involves no symbolic links, even if the input did traverse symbolic links — see the text you quoted.

Comment: You know, I believe the goal of my class (operating systems) is to understand how the core functionality of OS's work. I'm unsure if realpath would violate this. I was not aware of this function and will look into it. If it turns out to be fine, I'll accept your answer. In the meantime, the suggestion of using strstr (also wasn't aware of (not super familiar with c)) has been extremely beneficial.